# Can I replace TIP127 with TIP122 power transistor?

Tags: transistors, pcb

I have faulty PCB for hoverboard. A TIP127 has failed. I don't have the same. The one I have to replace it with is TIP122. Would there be any problem with this?

Comment: You can’t implicitly replace device A with device B by examining the data sheet. Can I put a Mercedes gearbox in a Skoda or vice versa.

Comment: @Andyaka Don't you mean "you can't implicitly replace device A with device B **without** examining the data sheet"?

Comment: One could do that given similar/same specifications of those devices. So far, we know they can't replace them with the current one since it's of a different doping. If they were poth PNP, I'd then discuss whether or not they could do that while citing the datasheets.

Comment: @JYelton no, although what I wrote was open to interpretation. What I should have said is that you cannot replace by ONLY reading the data sheets. In fact the main business of replacement is to understand what device A does in its current circuit so that device B can be chosen to work in that circuit. Data sheets alone will not guarantee successful replacement. However, you can rule out device B being usable as a replacement by looking only at the DSs.

Comment: @Andyaka But you can at least read the datasheet instead of choosing a component which has the same housing.

Comment: @Ariser-reinstateMonica you can do what you want but if you want my advice, you look at the schematics first then decide.

Comment: @Andyaka It was meant as a joke. Perhaps I should have marked it accordingly.

Comment: Aha internet comment payback.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't.

According to this [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TIP120-D.PDF), the TIP122 is NPN, while the TIP127 is a PNP transistor. You'll need another similarly rated PNP to work.